# How convert multi-column PDF files to readable PDF in 6 inches display devices?

Tags: kindle, pdf, conversion, file-format

What is the best way to convert multi-column PDF file into readable format in a 6 inch display devices like kindle?

Comment: are these PDFs scanned images or text files that are re-wrappable?

Comment: I dont know if it works well with scanned image. you may give it a try. I guess it is not suitable for scanned images

Comment: Why would I need to give it a try with what? I already converted scanned images, it is just cumbersome. Your question isn't clear about the PDF content **you** have, and that influences what kind of answers are useful for you.

Comment: my question is clear. your comment is not clear: "are these PDFs scanned images or text files that are re-wrappable?"

Comment: Referring to the PDF 1.7 specification: does your PDF have any of the standard decompression filters to render your page content, or does it specify text with TwoColumnXXXX in the PageLayout? Both can **look**  the same but need completely different approaches to display readable on a 6 inch device.

Comment: this is not a question about a specific file or a specific group of files. One may provide different answers which works for different type of PDFs

Comment: No the question  is unclear - in Stack Exchange questions should really only have one answer. You provide different questions for each type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading PDFs on Kindle device](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/15/reading-pdfs-on-kindle-device)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also check out [k2pdfopt](http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/) by Willus.

Comment: did you install it? I receive this error: Capcha entry incorrect.

Comment: The captcha worked fine for me.The web site uses the same type of images that are used for eye tests. I.e., if you don't look carefully, you might not see one of the three numbers because of the camouflage pattern.
If your captcha is rejected, click New Captcha and try again.
You'll always have to enter 3 numbers.

Comment: it is on the left of screen, didnt saw it!

Comment: this program is amazing. there are predefined options for different readers that adjust the page and dpi according to company standards

Answer (score 6):

I found [PaperCrop](https://code.google.com/archive/p/papercrop/) a very useful and powerful tool. It is free and highly customizable so you can either relay to automatic detection of columns and sections by program or customize each page format.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have created a python code for this purpose. It solves my problem and hope it will be helpful for others.

Background : I had 2 sided pdf document which I had to zoom for clarity. I decide to create this python application which will break 2 column page into 4 pages.

If you don't understand then : just run python3 main.py, and see if it is what you are looking into.

https://github.com/jojyjoseph/PDF-1-2-column-customization-for-Kindle

Comment: Welcome to SE-ebooks.  Your answer seems quite useful, thanks. But it may take a while for reactions because the question is 2 years old.  Just so that you do not wonder.

Answer (score 1):

I found this small Java utility [1].

Very simple to setup and quick to use and gives a pretty nice result on my Kindle.

[1] [https://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~somchai/cut2col/](https://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/%7Esomchai/cut2col/)