# kindle cannot highlight/select words in converted pdf

Tags: pdf, conversion

I converted scientific books using softwares introduced [here](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/6496/how-convert-multi-column-pdf-files-to-readable-pdf-in-6-inches-display-devices/6497#6497).
I am using kindle paperwhite and the problem is that i cannot select and long press any word in PDF. Whole the file looks like an image.

When I open converted PDFs in my PC, I see they are not images and I cannot select and copy an word.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Once converted, the PDFs are not images when viewed on your PC and you cannot select or copy text still?

Comment: Papercrop web page says it creates image sequences, not text in the PDF: "his program converts PDF documents such as articles, and academic papers into a PDF (or image sequence)". There are at least 2 types of PDFs: those which contain text which can be extracted, and those which are 100% images of page scans.

Comment: What paper-crop produce at the end is not 100% image because when you  open the pdf in computer, you can still select the text